# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, xampp

i see this error in my xampp/mysql/logs. what shoud i do?

2019-09-18 16:06:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2019-09-18 16:06:13 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot create log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.

2019-09-18 16:06:13 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error

2019-09-18 16:06:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...

2019-09-18 16:06:13 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.

2019-09-18 16:06:13 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.

2019-09-18 16:06:13 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

2019-09-18 16:06:13 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB

2019-09-18 16:06:13 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2019-09-18 16:14:28 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Are you sure you are using the right ib_logfiles to start up the database? Log sequence number in the ib_logfiles is 49468, less than the log sequence number in the first system tablespace file header, 1630815.

2019-09-18 16:14:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting a batch to recover 112 pages from redo log.

2019-09-18 16:14:28 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: We scanned the log up to 1603190. A checkpoint was at 49468 and the maximum LSN on a database page was 294254698. It is possible that the database is now corrupt!

2019-09-18 16:14:28 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=7] log sequence number 285914931 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1603199.

2019-09-18 16:14:28 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.

Comment: I don't see that error in your log? Was there anything before it that might give a clue as why it crashed, e.g. a failed memory allocation because you'd run out of RAM or your disk was full? But this may well be a MySQL issue not solvable from WordPress.

Comment: yes. i am so sorry. this my first experience. i edit my question.